# Pagination for search indexes on cloudant

Tags: node.js, pagination, cloudant

I have a cloudant db which contains documents for access logs of users. Example:

```
{
  "name": "John Doe", 
  "url": "somepage.html", 
  "dateaccessed": "2016-08-23T21:20:25.502Z"
}
```

I created a search index with a function:

```
function (doc) {
  if(doc.dateaccessed) {
    var d = new Date(doc.dateaccessed);
    index("dateaccessed", d.getTime(), {store: true});
  }
}
```

Now this setup is working as expected with just a normal query. Example

```
{
  q: 'dateaccessed:[1420041600000 TO 1471987625266]',
  include_docs: true,
  sort: '-dateaccessed<number>',
}
```

However, I wish to limit the results - let's say 5 at a time (which can be done with the "limit: 5" argument), and I want to somehow make a pagination - be able to move to the next 5 results or the previous 5 results.

I checked the cloudant documentation and there's an argument there called "bookmark" (https://cloudant.com/for-developers/search/) but I'm not sure how to use it.

May I request for any insights on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Cloudant documentation](https://docs.cloudant.com/search.html) shows examples on how to use bookmarks, but the gist is that you get a bookmark from the server in your search response, when requesting the next page, you use the bookmark received in your request with the `bookmark` parameter in either your JSON object for POST, or in the query params for GET.

Comment: 1 - I executed the query for the first time. 2 - Retrieved the bookmark from the response and passed it to the next query. I was able to retrieve the next set of results. 

With this I could created previous/next buttons but as for actual pagination (page number) I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: You can't. There is no way to know the number of pages. You also can't determine if you're on the last page. You have to make a request to find out of there is a next page.

Comment: @rhyshort, thats actually not true. Because when you do the initial query you ill be given a total_rows count. So once you have done the initial query, pagination is possible.